# Null pointer exception in String[]

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am not sure why I am getting a `NullPointerException` on the line containing the `while` loop.

Originally when the `String[] input` is created. It is filled with `null` so maybe that is why I was getting the error. I tried to fix this by adding this bit of code to change that:

```
    for (String k : input) {
        k = "empty";
    }
```

This is probably the wrong approach so I am still getting the error.

code:

```
String[] input = new String[3];
        while(!input[0].equals("exit")) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            input = sc.nextLine().split(" ", 3);
            switch(input[0]) {
                // vi
                case "vi":
                    System.out.println("hi");
                    break;
                // ls
                case "ls":
                    break;
                // mkdir
                case "mkdir":
                    break;
                // pwd  
                case "pwd":
                    break;
            }   
        }
```

Comment: You can't use an enhanced for loop to assign array elements.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
for (String k : input) {
    k = "empty";
}
```

is effectively equivalent to

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    String k = input[i];
    k = "empty";
}
```

Changing the reference `k` does not affect the reference in the array.

Just do

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    input[i] = "empty";
}
```

I'm not sure what your `while` loop is meant to do so I will not comment on that.